# How can I access parsed_variables returned by broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, parsing, broadcastreceiver, ussd

I m using Hover SDK to automate USSD sessions in the background of my Android applications.

I have installed the SDK in my Application created an action and set up a parser till now everything works well but when I wanted to get the data from it in the broadcastReceiver I didn't find the "parsed_variables" in the intent.hasExtra("parsed_variables")

```
[the Action in the Dashboard][1]
```

and the Dashboard indicates that everything was ok I even get my parsed variable

there is how I did it
the Activity where I start the USSD session

````
private TransactionReceiver mReceiver = new TransactionReceiver();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_ask_for_permission);


   ImageButton getNumberBtn =  findViewById(R.id.getNumberBtn);
   getNumberBtn.setEnabled(true);
   getNumberBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new HoverParameters.Builder( GetPhoneNumber.this)
                   .request("fc90f556") .buildIntent();
           startActivityForResult(i, 0);
           mReceiver.onReceive(AskForPermission.this,i);
       }

}```



in the BroadcastReceiver class, I just Loged the data from the intent 



   ```public class TransactionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String TAG = "Receiver";

public TransactionReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
   String uuid = intent.getStringExtra("uuid");

   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   if (bundle != null) {
       for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
           Log.e(TAG, key + " : " + (bundle.get(key) != null ? bundle.get(key) : "NULL"));
       }
   }


}
````

according to the [Documentaion][1], I should get the field "parsed_variables" in the  intent received but All I get was

````
2020-03-19 14:43:51.960 9859-9859/com.Houssem.Foxy E/Receiver: extras : {}
2020-03-19 14:43:51.960 9859-9859/com.Houssem.Foxy E/Receiver: private_extras : {}
2020-03-19 14:43:51.961 9859-9859/com.Houssem.Foxy E/Receiver: dev_style : 2131624139
2020-03-19 14:43:51.961 9859-9859/com.Houssem.Foxy E/Receiver: env : 0
2020-03-19 14:43:51.961 9859-9859/com.Houssem.Foxy E/Receiver: processing_msg : NULL
2020-03-19 14:43:51.961 9859-9859/com.Houssem.Foxy E/Receiver: action_id : fc90f556
2020-03-19 14:43:51.961 9859-9859/com.Houssem.Foxy E/Receiver: timeout_ms : 10000
2020-03-19 14:43:51.961 9859-9859/com.Houssem.Foxy E/Receiver: final_msg_length : 5000
2020-03-19 14:43:51.961 9859-9859/com.Houssem.Foxy E/Receiver: header_msg : NULL```  


someone help me, please


  [1]: https://docs.usehover.com/parsing
````